# any config for rundeck to cross-domian api call from other domain

Tags: ajax, cors, rundeck

I'm using jquery ajax , to call the rest api of Rundeck

like

```
$.ajax(
    {
       url:"{rundeck_url}/api/1/job/5?authtoken=D4CUK8DD5DP4sovSR7p9UUnd5DnvU3do"
    }       
);
```

but get error from brower for doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {rundeck_url}/api/1/job/5?authtoken=D4CUK8DD5DP4sovSR7p9UUnd5DnvU3do. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{site_url}' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any config to set up the  header for Cross-Origin in rundeck ?

Thanks

ENV:

rundeck:1.4.2
API Reference Version: 3

Comment: Is rundeck proxyed through apache httpd? it's very easy in that case

Comment: Thanks @guido , It should be a solution, and also one [enhancement](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/696) is submit

Comment: @AjaxZhang can you please let me know how u resolved this issue..even  Im stuck with same

Comment: as guido said,   work-around is to put nginx/apache httpd in front and have it serve CORS headers for you @user7350714